# why it returns null?

Tags: java

I have 3 classes that I have written some part of them below.when i write`this statement in AddStudent class ,it will show abcd1234 which is the password, but when I write it in the MainFrame class it will return null.why???    (I send my management object from MainFrame to the AddStudent with AddStudent's constructor)   (***I need the management object's information which is created in the AddStudent class in the mainframe )
what should I do?***

```
management.getStudentsPassword();
```

my AddStudent class:

```
public class AddStudent extends javax.swing.JDialog {

private SystemManagement management;


/** Creates new form AddStudent */
public AddStudent(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, SystemManagement management) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    this.management = management;

}
```

my MainFrame class:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form MainFrame */
private SystemManagement management;
.
.
.}
```

my SystemManagement class:

```
private String studentsPass;
...
public void setStudentspassword(String password){
studentsPass = password;
}
public String getStudentsPassword(){
return studentsPass;
}
```

Comment: You need to show how it's wired together in the MainFrame class...

Also, it seems to me like this should be tagged with 'homework'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Reason one* - password has not been set, when you call getStudentsPass() in MainFrame.

*Reason two* - The SystemManagement object you use in MainFrame and the one you get in AddStudent are simply not the same.

Hard to tell without more code. But I favour Reason one - check the program flow, when is the password set, when do you try to get it.

Comment: I set the password with setStudentPassword() in the AddStudent class. in the AddStudent class my sentence return the correct password but in the MainFrame it doesn't.

Comment: I think that the Dialog `AddStudent` is spawned from `MainFrame`. Check if you really call `getStudentsPassword()` in `MainFrame` after the Dialog was visible and not before.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question where setStudentPassword is being called from, it can't be being called if it is still leaving studentsPass null.